# Automatic Object Construction in Function Parameters by Passing Constructor Parameters

Tags: c++, constructor, parameter-passing

Can you explain why the following code compiles and runs?  What is the concept at play here, and what are the limitations/requirements for such a methodology to work?

```
class string_wrapper
{
public:
    string_wrapper(string i_string);

    string m_value;
    int m_length;
};

string_wrapper::string_wrapper(string i_string)
{
    m_value = i_string;
    m_length = i_string.length();
}

void bar(string_wrapper i_param)
{
    cout << i_param.m_value << std::endl;
}

void foo()
{
    string test_string = "test1";

    bar(test_string);
}

int main()
{
    test_function_b();
}
```

Output:

```
test1
```

I would expect this code to not compile.  foo() is passing a string parameter to bar(), when bar only takes a string_wrapper parameter.  However, the compiler is smart enough to know that it can use the string parameter as a parameter to a constructor for a string_parameter object, which presumably is then passed on as the actual parameter to bar().

Is this behavior within the C++ standard, or unique to my compiler (Visual Studio 2017, version 15.9, in this case)?  Any insight or terminology I can use for further research would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this might help you: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution Your hunch about what the compiler is doing is quite correct, but if you change the constructor to be `explicit` it will fail to compile.

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/nnEN3D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats going on here is *implicit construction*. You are right about the compiler being 'smart' enough to know that you can create a `string_wrapper` out of a `std::string` and so does it automatically for you.

To stop this happening you can use the `explcit` keyword like this:

```cpp
...
explicit string_wrapper(string i_string);
...
```

The `explicit` keyword tells the compiler that you do not want it to automatically construct `string_wrapper` objects for you out of `std::string`'s. This can stop hard to track down bugs because it prevents accidentally constructing objects (especially on function returns and when passing arguments).

Implicit construction can happen when an object has only one non-defaulted parameter (implicit conversion is something you should research as well). It can be a powerful tool and can allow things like proxy classes and transparent APIs (i.e `std::vector`'s reference class). Generally you should declare single parameter (or single undefaulted value) constructors (and conversion operators) `explicit` unless you are making a design decision not too.